# How can I set active profile via annotation in spring?

Tags: java, spring

How can I set active profile via annotation in spring ?

For example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@ActiveProfiles( profiles = {ApplicationProfiles.TEST} )
public class CacheManagerTest {
     ...
}
```

For JUnit test this works perfect, but how can I init production application context ? (I do not have any main method/сlasses)

Comment: What type of config are you using the in the prod app? Is this a web app?

Comment: Hi @Malahov, hope my answer solves your problem. using the standard system property is the usual way of enabling profiles in productive environments. If this works for you, please do not forget to mark my answer as the right one. Cheers.

Answer (score 11):

You can pass in the active profile(s) at runtime using the [`spring.profiles.active`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html#ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME) property:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="profile1,profile2"
```

See the [SpringSource blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) on the introduction of profiles.

Comment: Can you link a documentation on this feature?

Comment: The question was about annotation. Not a property.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using making a standalone application or web application you pass active profile these way, according to [Spring blog](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/)

Activation in Web application

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>production</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Activation with manually created context

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("dev");
ctx.load("classpath:/com/bank/config/xml/*-config.xml");
ctx.refresh();
```

Comment: I do not have web.xml (this is not web application). If activation with manually, that the idea is lost through configuration profiles.

Comment: The first block of code is wrong. the @Profile does not "activate" a profile, it just describes that that configuration will be activated when the profile in question is activated.