# Jenkins: Deploy different applicationContext for different URL

Tags: java, spring, jenkins, web-deployment

I use Jenkins to deploy my application to two environments, work and test.

Problem: Work and test environment must use different databases.

I use Spring and define path to database in my `applicationContext.xml`.

1. How to deploy two different application contexts depend on deploying path?
2. Is it possible to do only with help of Jenkins?

Comment: You may need to specify a properties files. Set up some profiles in your project pom to fill in placeholders for your context. Try the [maven-resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to solve your main question

> Work and test environment must use different databases.

you should use Spring profiles and define several data sources (and other beans if you needed them) [quick example](http://diarmuidmoloney.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/spring-environments/)

Then, you can run your application with different command line Spring's profile arguments `-Dspring.profiles.active=<your-profile,your-another-profile,etc>` or specify them in `web.xml` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17315539/2964811)

[Useful Spring blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/#enter-bean-definition-profiles)

Hope this helps.